# What does the Klingon say to Odo?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, klingon, klingon-language

In the beginning of "The Way of the Warrior," Klingons harass Morn, and Odo comes to his aid. One Klingon insults him in his own tongue. Garak tells him that "Odo has no mother." Is it known what the entire insult was?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [the script](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/474.txt)<sup>1</sup>, the line (with translation) is:

> **Drex:** Lohd Zoss-lee chaw-KU sohk jaTAL? (Does your mother let you talk to men?)
>
> <sup>*Deep Space Nine* Season 4 Episode 1: "The Way of the Warrior"</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> Archived by [Star Trek Minutiae](http://www.st-minutiae.com/index.html) from "other published sources"

Comment: Those are all words from the Klingon language devised by Marc Okrand, though not in proper grammatical form or order:
loD = man,
SoSlI' = your mother,
chaw'qu' = permit (emphatic),
SoH = you,
jatlh = speak.

In Okrandian grammar, the sentence should be {loDvaD bIjatlh chaw''a' SoSlI'?}

Comment: That insult is awesome. It sounds Shakespearian. I love it and will use it myself at the proper time.